# show currency symbol of SAR in both store view

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, currency

I have store in two views Arabic and English. if I delete this code from

```
/home/store/public_html/site/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/ar_SA.xml
```

```
<numbers>
<currencyFormats numberSystem="latn">
<currencyFormatLength>
<currencyFormat type="standard">
<!-- <pattern>¤#0.00</pattern> !-->
</currencyFormat>
</currencyFormatLength>
</currencyFormats>
```

the currency code show like ر.س in both store view.

also, I can't find SAR currency in root.xml

I found the path of this symbol "ر.س" in

```
/home/stor/public_html/m4/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/ar.xml
```

2- How to be SR or SAR in English view?

3- how to solve this issue without changing in core files?

4- how to change a position of currency yo right? I edit the position to 
`'position'  => self::RIGHT,`in  `vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Currency.php` but it has shown between price.

[image]

Magento CE 2.1.9

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384750/magento-2-how-to-customize-currency-symbol-and-format-based-on-locale

Comment: @PYYick the path of functions are for magento 1. can you help me to know the path in magento 2

Comment: This answer is M2 already

Comment: @PYYick ok i found this zendframework1/library/Zend/Currency.php what about public function formatTxt on module-directory/Model/Currency.php?

Comment: The file is located under vendor/magento. You can override formatTxt to customize the currency format.

Comment: @PYYick i add some update can you help ?

Comment: You solved first 3 problems already? So the real problem is 4?

Comment: @pyyick yes, but for third question, i change from core file

Comment: Can this help you? https://beacots.com/magento-2-change-currency-symbol-position/